# The property ORDERED does not prevent switching TODO state

Tags: org-mode, todo

a minimal example to get my question clear (copied from the Org Manual to my org file, only changed the last line):

```
* Parent
:PROPERTIES:
:ORDERED: t
:END:

** TODO a
** TODO b, needs to wait for (a)
** DONE c, needs to wait for (a) and (b)
```

In my understanding setting the last line from TODO to DONE state should not be possible because of the ORDERED property. But in my org file I can do this.

I did not find the variable where I can control this behaviour, so I would kindly ask for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable is mentioned just above [the example](https://orgmode.org/manual/TODO-dependencies.html).
So you should set/customize `org-enforce-todo-dependencies` to `t`.